# deserialize a class whose assembly and namespace has changed

Tags: serialization, namespaces, assemblies

I have the problem described here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/csharplanguage/thread/b310c71a-2479-4a93-888a-29294cecbe09

They give a solution using a SerializationBinder. Is there another alternative?? Like decorating my classes with a different namespace and assembly?? The reason is that I have some classes with this problem used many times, and I have to add the line "formatter.Binder = ..." in each part of the code. It would be easier to apply my hipothetic second solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the assembly version changes, serialized objects become invalid. I once made changes to the source code of [Protobuf-Net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) to avoid the version check, and it was fairly easy to do so. However, it can lead to unexpected results (data ending up in the wrong fields), unless you avoid the implicit fields, and set an index to each field manually using annotations. That's the advantage or Protobuf-Net, that you have control over the order of the fields in the serialized stream.

Another solution is to use [custom serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)? Something like:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyObject : ISerializable 
{
  public int n1;
  public int n2;
  public String str;

  public MyObject()
  {
  }

  protected MyObject(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
  {
    n1 = info.GetInt32("i");
    n2 = info.GetInt32("j");
    str = info.GetString("k");
  }
[SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, 
SerializationFormatter =true)]

public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
  {
    info.AddValue("i", n1);
    info.AddValue("j", n2);
    info.AddValue("k", str);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a valid approach but the binder is simpler. Thanks for the answer. I think there are just these two possibilities.